# mapstruct does not set relationship properly on a bi-directional OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa, dto, mapstruct

I have a JPA one to many bi-directional association. In my code i set the relationship on both side. But the generated mapstruct code seems not setting the relationship properly. I mean it is setting on one side.

I pasted part of my code. The line which i commented is added manually by me.
It should have been generated by mapstruct

```
    derivativeFuture.setDerivativeExecutions( derivativeExecutionDTOSetToDerivativeExecutionSet( derivativeDTO.getDerivativeExecutions() ) );
    //derivativeFuture.getDerivativeExecutions().forEach(derivativeExecution -> { derivativeExecution.setDerivative(derivativeFuture); });


protected Set<DerivativeExecution> derivativeExecutionDTOSetToDerivativeExecutionSet(Set<DerivativeExecutionDTO> set) {
    if ( set == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Set<DerivativeExecution> set1 = new HashSet<DerivativeExecution>( Math.max( (int) ( set.size() / .75f ) + 1, 16 ) );
    for ( DerivativeExecutionDTO derivativeExecutionDTO : set ) {
        set1.add( derivativeExecutionDTOToDerivativeExecution( derivativeExecutionDTO ) );
    }

    return set1;
}


protected DerivativeExecution derivativeExecutionDTOToDerivativeExecution(DerivativeExecutionDTO derivativeExecutionDTO) {
    if ( derivativeExecutionDTO == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    DerivativeExecution derivativeExecution = new DerivativeExecution();

    derivativeExecution.setPhysicalQuantity( derivativeExecutionDTO.getPhysicalQuantity() );
    derivativeExecution.setExchangeQuantity( derivativeExecutionDTO.getExchangeQuantity() );
    derivativeExecution.setPurchaseSaleIndicator( derivativeExecutionDTO.getPurchaseSaleIndicator() );
    derivativeExecution.setQuotePricingStartDate( derivativeExecutionDTO.getQuotePricingStartDate() );
    derivativeExecution.setQuotePricingEndDate( derivativeExecutionDTO.getQuotePricingEndDate() );
    derivativeExecution.setContractExecutionId( derivativeExecutionDTO.getContractExecutionId() );

    return derivativeExecution;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options: adder_prefered : http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#collection-mapping-strategies or using a context: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-jpa-child-parent.